# PHP auto minify. Is there any?

Tags: php, javascript, css

I use PHP Minify and it's great. But my question, is there any PHP plugin or something, which would automatically detect javascript/css code and minify it automatically? Thank you.

Comment: Unless it's generated dynamically, it's best to minify beforehand. It's pointless to minify at each page request.

Comment: @pimvdb: so it's better to me just get all javascript code from all .php files and put it in one file? And what about if I need to edit something? Thank you;.

Comment: If you have JavaScript code in your PHP files something is wrong anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript minifier?

Take a look [here](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/combine-minify-javascript-php/)

```
require_once('jsmin-1.1.1.php');

$files = glob("/path/to/js/merge/*.js");
$js = "";
foreach($files as $file) {
    $js .= JSMin::minify(file_get_contents($file));
}

file_put_contents("/path/to/js/combined.js", $js);
// or to output it: echo $js;
```

Comment: Random order? Might not be such a good idea when using libraries other scripts depend on.

Comment: he can use it as he wants. I just gave him idea how to start

Comment: When I use this library (jsMin), it's awfully slow

Answer (score 0):

Do look at https://github.com/web-developer/Resource-Handler. This is a on the fly compressor and minifyer for your js. This requires least configuration or hassle, unlike the other one suggested .

**[RESOURCE HANDLER](https://github.com/web-developer/Resource-Handler)**