# Minify CSS and JavaScript files with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, minify

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP auto minify. Is there any?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767223/php-auto-minify-is-there-any)

I'm using PHP minify (http://code.google.com/p/minify/)

I have to go to my webpage, create the url's, click upload, copy the the link of the new compressed file into my PHP file as explained here: http://www.mrclay.org/2008/09/19/minify-21-on-mrclayorg/

This works fine, but how can this be automated? Is there a PHP class for this or can I use one of the PHP classes already included in minify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two main options really.

1. Use cURL to call the google code minifier. http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php
2. Use a different minifier that you can run locally. Try:
   http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/ (Requires Java runtime)
   http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html (Windows only)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a wrapper with CURL to send your files to the server, gets the returned text and outputs it to the client.

Beware, though, that it will slow down your server a lot (it will minify the code every time someone asks for it). So you would need a caching mechanism to do it only once.